# Programatically fetch macOS Version using golang

Tags: macos, go

I want to fetch macOS version in golang.
Basically want to check whether the macOS is >= Big Sur.

Found goInfo package. But it doesn't provide the required details.
Tried syscall package but the solution works only on Linux.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with golang, but the `sw_vers` command can help. You can get the macOS version by running `sw_vers -productVersion` from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [unix.Uname](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys@v0.7.0/unix#Uname) to get the release version of darwin. According to [the release history of darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)#Release_history), the corresponding darwin version of Big Sur is `20.x.x`.

See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
    var uts unix.Utsname
    if err := unix.Uname(&uts); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sysname := unix.ByteSliceToString(uts.Sysname[:])
    release := unix.ByteSliceToString(uts.Release[:])

    fmt.Printf("sysname: %s\nrelease: %s\n", sysname, release)

    if sysname == "Darwin" {
        dotPos := strings.Index(release, ".")
        if dotPos == -1 {
            fmt.Printf("invalid release value: %s\n", release)
            return
        }

        major := release[:dotPos]
        majorVersion, err := strconv.Atoi(major)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("invalid release value: %s, %v\n", release, err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("macOS >= Big Sur:", majorVersion >= 20)
    }
}
```

Output on my computer:

```
sysname: Darwin
release: 22.3.0
macOS >= Big Sur: true
```

Reference: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.20/src/cmd/internal/osinfo/os_unix.go